# does it make sense to ask: Who did you make cry?

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to ask the following

> Who is the person that you made cry?

It sounds a bit awkward to ask like this

> Who did you make cry?

Would it be correct?

Comment: Just to be clear, you made someone else cry, or someone made you cry?

Comment: I am asking someone who he/she made cry

Comment: Yes, *"Who did you make cry?"* is the normal construction.  I agree that it sounds a little awkward (and I will let someone else explain why it might not be technically correct) but it's probably the most normal way to say it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your sentences rely on the pattern `make someone|something {verb}`

> The news made her leap for joy.
>
> The heat made the chocolate melt.
>
> You made someone cry.
>
> Who is the person (that) you made cry?
>
> Who did you make cry?

Your one question uses the **did** + bare infinitive form of the past tense. The other uses the simple past **made**.

Both are idiomatic, and both would be perfectly natural given the proper conversational context.  To my ear, the second one sounds more natural than the first. It is more direct, less verbose, and the syntax is used quite often. It is not a rare usage by any means.

Answer (score 3):

While it does sound a little awkward, it is the correct construction. Perhaps it sounds odd only because a more common situation would be to ask
"Who made you cry?"

You can tell when someone has been crying, so it is natural to ask the reason.  But you can't tell that someone has made another person cry, so the context is less likely to arise.

I can imagine a conversation:

> *Son:*  I got a detention for making one of the girls cry at school today.
>
> *Father:*  Who did you make cry!? What did you do to her!?
>
> *Son:*  I just said ...